# meta exchange Yearling badge without reputations bonus

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

Yesterday , I received a [yearling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=246904) badge on my meta exchange site.

```
  Active member for 1 year earning at least 200 reputations
```

As the tag discription says "I was active on this site for 1 year, and I have earned 200 reputations bonus.
My account is 1 year 10 months old and I am active on this site since then. Also I did not receive 200 reputations bonus.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The association bonus is awarded once per account, not every time you hit 200 reputation on a site.

You originally received your reputation bonus on January 5, 2015, and it was correctly applied to [your profile here on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/246904/starkeen?tab=reputation):

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

You just passed 200 reputation yesterday:

[image: screenshot]

Your account did not satisfy both conditions (have an account for a year **and** earn at least 200 rep) until that time, so you were only awarded the badge then.

I fail to see where there is a bug.